# How to make postprocessing data uploaded from file before store in DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in RoR.

I need to process data after I get it from file.
I see two way to done it.

Application have 3 models:

```
Data
Segment - belongs to data
Point - belongs to Segment
```

First way is:

1. Make classes (< Object) and define same fields like in models
2. Read data to objects (classes in 1.)
3. Process data
4. Upload data to data base

In this way I have one question - what is the best place to define classes? Model, /lib, etc?

Second way is:

1. Read data to DB
2. Process data
3. Update in DB

In this way I have another question - how to update a bunch of points in one transaction?

Could you please help me to approach it?

Update:
May be I should read file data in array of hashes, process it and upload to DB?

Comment: which kind of processing are u gonna do? how much time-consuming this action can be?

Comment: It will be "moving average" and "median" filter. For one object in Data will be about 5 segments and in each segment about 100-150 points. Don't know is it will be heavy load or not for server (1 core 2Ghz, 1 Gb RAM, regular hdd 7200 rpm)

Comment: I would said you should use some nosql to store incoming requests (without any processing at all if format allows you) and then use a background job to go through them.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but I'll google about it. I want to show report and give permanent link to user after file uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as Rails is designed to work as web server that will be my best approach:

```
routes.rb
  post '/uploads/log/', to: 'logs#create'

uploads_controller.rb

  def create
    @upload = Upload.new(parsed_upload_file) #define a method to parse the filetype
    if @upload.save
      #actions after save like show the parsed result or whatever
    else
      #display errors like format issues or actions to perform
    end
  end

uploads.rb #model
class Upload << ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor #if you need attributes not defined in the db but in the file
  before_create :pre_process_data


  private
  def pre_process_data
     #actions to preprocess data
  end
end
```

And define a form with the upload fields or the url.

I like this approach as long as you will have a nice inteface to upload the posts. Even you can define urls to get them, or a cron to do the automatic request with the file to this url.

And for the other question, I dislike transactions as long as you might need to know which one failed. I rather recommend to do this:

```
def bunch_update
   @invalid_points = []
   points_array.each do |point|
     new_point = Point.new(point)
     @invalid_points << new_point unless new_point.valid?
   end
   points_array.each {|point| point.save} if @invalid_points.empty?
end
```

With this you will be able to use in the view:

```
@invalid_points.each do |point|
  point.errors.full_messages
end
```

To now what failed on this points.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It much better than my attempts.

Comment: Could you help me with this - how can I implement `attr_accessor` in Rails 4.0.2 ?

Comment: In the model: attr_accessor :attribute1, :attribute2